# I have a made toolbar and want to show on side menu screen with navigation drawer but unable to get

Tags: android

I have a made toolbar and want to show on side menu screen with navigation drawer but unable to get . Please see the code & suggest to what should i do for same ?
i am unable to set title on toolbar & menu icon is not showing on tollbar. I am stuck on that.

after clicking side menu screen option should come as MyOrders,mywallet,Reatecard,Offers,Help,Notifi  . But it is coming by defalut my orders .

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import handyman.com.handyman.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import handyman.com.handyman.model.NavDrawerItem;

public class Profile extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[]   navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    private Toolbar supportActionBar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        /*ActionBar setSupportActionBar;
         setSupportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);*/
       /* getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);*/
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.manu, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name )
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                supportActionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                supportActionBar.setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }



    }

    public void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar supportActionBar) {
        this.supportActionBar = supportActionBar;
    }


    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        android.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new MyOrders();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new MyWallet();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new RateCard();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new Offers();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new Help();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new Notifi();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        supportActionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Profile"
    android:id="@+id/app_name">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Hi user"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:divider="@color/list_divider"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"
                android:background="@color/list_background"/>
        </FrameLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:background="@color/list_background"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"

        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all : to set title in the toolbar add this  `app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"` to your `toolbar.xml` and in your `style.xml` file you have to create the style :

```
<style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWithe</item>
</style>
```

then you could use `toolbar.setText` in your `profile.java` or in your `manifest.xml` under your class declaration you can add `android:label="@string/name_to_show_in_toolbar"`.

Second of all : in your `profile.xml` try to make `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout />` in the top of the file and the other component under it like that :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="7dp">

   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Profile"
    android:id="@+id/app_name">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>


    <!-- the other componennts -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

hope ti helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You have to simply do one thing that is you have to make custom toolbar and after that include that custom  layout in toolbar like the way i will shown you below in code snippet.

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/topbar"
            android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

and after that  set title in your textview which you made in custom toolbar layout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NavigationView inside of drawer layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

app_bar_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dip"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- This is a centered logo -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start"/>
            />

            <include
                layout="@layout/ab_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the support library toolbar, you need to use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`...

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity
```

The `Activity` class does not even have the `setSupportActionBar()` method, so I'm guessing your code should not be getting compiled right now.